# how to fetch local api in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm a new one, I'm trying to fetch my own api on local,this what I do:
in "src/server.js"

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/api", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile("api.js", { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

then I use creat-react-app to create a react project, how can I call my api in App.js?
if my situation is not complete, please tell me.

Q1:with server.js, after I run "node server.js", I can can call this file in browser that means I have done an api, right?
Q2:how can I get value from my api.js in App.js without cors problem?

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors for cors. You can get API data using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: [You may have to add a proxy prop to your package.json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should add your request address into package.json file. For example if you want to send http request to `https://localhost:5000/`, you should add `"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"` line into your package.json file.

After adding this line, you can send http request without getting CORS error.

Also you can use fetch function to sending request and getting response from server side in your react code(App.js).

```
fetch('/api')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```